# Add the customer's company in the new order Email

Tags: magento

How can I add the customer's company to the customer address (in the new order Email)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `app/code/core/Customer/etc/config.xml`, Magento defines the formats for addresses. If you want to modify *all* html-formatted addresses to contain company info, you can override this file (specifically, the path `default/customer/address_templates/html`):

```
<html><![CDATA[{{depend prefix}}{{var prefix}} {{/depend}}{{var firstname}} {{depend middlename}}{{var middlename}} {{/depend}}{{var lastname}}{{depend suffix}} {{var suffix}}{{/depend}}<br/>
{{depend company}}{{var company}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if street1}}{{var street1}}<br />{{/if}}
{{depend street2}}{{var street2}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street3}}{{var street3}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{depend street4}}{{var street4}}<br />{{/depend}}
{{if city}}{{var city}},  {{/if}}{{if region}}{{var region}}, {{/if}}{{if postcode}}{{var postcode}}{{/if}}<br/>
{{var country}}<br/>
{{depend telephone}}T: {{var telephone}}{{/depend}}
{{depend fax}}<br/>F: {{var fax}}{{/depend}}]]></html>
```

Otherwise, you could create your own module and add a new address format in your XML config file. Then, you would need to modify your email templates to use the new format:

```
{{var order.getBillingAddress().format('yourformat')}}
```

Comment: Thanks, 
this line in not clear, is that a template file ??
the path default/customer/address_templates/html

Comment: I guess the best term would be that it is an XPath. I was trying to communicate where in the XML document this would belong (since that XML file is pretty significant).

Comment: Thanks a lot Joe....Is it possible to get Customer order qauntity and Product information using this template. please specify the detail path where I need to do changes.